# Getting the indexes from an object

Tags: javascript, object, indexing

So I'm creating a text-based RPG and have an object containing the functions for the player's attacks. I want to allow the player to type in the index of the function to call it. I tried to use a for loop for this, but as far as I know you can't call a function using a variable. Any ideas?
Here's the code I'm stuck on - I'll post the full code below:

```
function playHit(skill)
{
    moveIndex = prompt("Your turn! Enter the number of the move you want to use.")
    moveChosen = abilitiesObject[moveIndex]
    for (move in moveList)
    {
        if (move === moveChosen)
        {
            moveList.move
        }
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
abilities = ["0. Slash", " 1. Push"]
abilitiesObject = ["Slash", "Push"]
function getMoves()
{
    document.getElementById("moves").innerHTML = abilities
}
var moveList = new Object()
moveList.Slash = function(damage)
{
    if (damage < 5)
    {
        Poutcome = 0
    }
    else if (damage >= 5)
    {
        Poutcome = 1
    }
    Psmackdown = (Poutcome + att) - eDef
    alert("You swing wildly! The monster takes " + Psmackdown + " points of damage.")
    eHp = eHp - Psmackdown
}

moveList.Push = function(damage)
{
    if (damage < 5)
    {
        Poutcome = -1
    }
    else if (damage > 9)
    {
        Poutcome = 2
        alert("You shove the monster into a spike pit!")
    }
    else
    {
        Poutcome = 0
    }
    Psmackdown = (Poutcome + att) - eDef
    alert("You shove the monster with all your might! The monster takes " + Psmackdown + " points of damage")
}


function playHit(skill)
{
    moveIndex = prompt("Your turn! Enter the number of the move you want to use.")
    moveChosen = abilitiesObject[moveIndex]
    for (move in moveList)
    {
        if (move === moveChosen)
        {
            moveList.move
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem? My solution helped you?

Answer (score 2):

You need this:

```
var keys = Object.keys(abilitiesObject);
```

Ref.: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys

You maybe also need the Object.keys polyfill to have compatibility with older browsers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys#Polyfill

Look at this:

```js
var player = {
  
  moves: {
    push: function() {
       document.write('Push!!');
    },
  
    smash: function() {
       document.write('Smash!!');
    }
  }
};

var abilities = Object.keys(player.moves);


var move = prompt("Your turn! Enter the number of the move you want to use.\r\n Options: " + abilities);

// Execute
if (player.moves[move]) {
  player.moves[move]();
}
```

Comment: `Object.keys()` doesn't guarantee order